# Is is possible to use python protobuf in server side and java protobuf in android app?

Tags: java, python, protocol-buffers

[Google's protobuff](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/) library is amazing. I have used java protobuff in server side and android app side. I was wondering if its possible to use python protobuff in server side and java protobuf in app side. I think it should be as in android side we serialize the data and then send over the network and on server side we deserialize the data. protobuff library should be able to handle the conversion right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use python protobuf on server and java protobuf on client.
Take a look into the various examples: https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/examples